Problem importing NSIDC .nc and .xml files into R
I'm trying to import daily sea-ice concentration grids from the NSIDC into R in a raster/SpatRaster format.
The NSIDC website generates a Python script to download the desired file (https://nsidc.org/data/data-access-tool/NSIDC-0051/versions/2). When running this script, two files are downloaded for each day:
NSIDC0051_SEAICE_PS_N25km_19790101_v2.0.nc
NSIDC0051_SEAICE_PS_N25km_19790101_v2.0.nc.xml
Two additionnal files are automatically downloaded for each month (not sure why, since this is supposed to be daily data):
NSIDC0051_SEAICE_PS_N25km_197901_v2.0.nc
NSIDC0051_SEAICE_PS_N25km_197901_v2.0.nc.xml
I have tried to import the .nc files corresponding to daily concentrations using several methods. I tried to use the function terra::rast():
> sea_ice <- terra::rast("04_raw_data/sea_ice/NSIDC_05_2024/NSIDC0051_SEAICE_PS_N25km_19790101_v2.0.nc")
Error: [rast] cannot open this file as a SpatRaster: NSIDC_05_2024/NSIDC0051_SEAICE_PS_N25km_19790101_v2.0.nc
In addition: Warning message:
`NSIDC0051_SEAICE_PS_N25km_19790101_v2.0.nc' not recognized as a supported file format. (GDAL error 4)

I have tried to use ncdf4::nc_open. This doesn't produce an error, however, there doesn't seem to be any sea-ice concentration measurements in the R object:
> nc_file <- nc_open("NSIDC0051_SEAICE_PS_N25km_19790101_v2.0.nc")
> print(nc_file)
File NSIDC0051_SEAICE_PS_N25km_19790101_v2.0.nc (NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4):

     1 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        char crs[]   (Contiguous storage)  
            grid_mapping_name: polar_stereographic
            straight_vertical_longitude_from_pole: -45
            false_easting: 0
            false_northing: 0
            latitude_of_projection_origin: 90
            standard_parallel: 70
            long_name: NSIDC_NH_PolarStereo_25km
            longitude_of_prime_meridian: 0
            semi_major_axis: 6378273
            inverse_flattening: 298.279411123064
            proj4text: +proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs
            crs_wkt: PROJCS["NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North",GEOGCS["Unspecified datum based upon the Hughes 1980 ellipsoid",DATUM["Not_specified_based_on_Hughes_1980_ellipsoid",SPHEROID["Hughes 1980",6378273,298.279411123061,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7058"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6054"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4054"]],PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",70],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3411"]]
            spatial_ref: PROJCS["NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North",GEOGCS["Unspecified datum based upon the Hughes 1980 ellipsoid",DATUM["Not_specified_based_on_Hughes_1980_ellipsoid",SPHEROID["Hughes 1980",6378273,298.279411123061,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7058"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6054"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4054"]],PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",70],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3411"]]
            srid: urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3411
            GeoTransform: -3850000 25000 0 5850000 0 -25000 

     3 dimensions:
        x  Size:304 
            standard_name: projection_x_coordinate
            coverage_content_type: coordinate
            long_name: x
            short_name: x
            axis: X
            units: meters
            valid_range: -3850000
             valid_range: 3750000
        y  Size:448 
            standard_name: projection_y_coordinate
            coverage_content_type: coordinate
            long_name: y
            short_name: y
            axis: Y
            units: meters
            valid_range: -5350000
             valid_range: 5850000
        time  Size:1   *** is unlimited *** 
            standard_name: time
            coverage_content_type: coordinate
            units: days since 1970-01-01 00:00:00
            long_name: ANSI date
            calendar: standard
            axis: T

I don't understand why the third dimension would be time, and not sea-ice concentration.
Finally, I have tried the raster::raster and raster::brick functions, which produce the following error:
>     file_l <- raster(NSIDC0051_SEAICE_PS_N25km_19790101_v2.0.nc)
Error in if (ndims == 1) { : argument is of length zero

I trust that the problem comes from what I'm doing, not from the NSIDC files. So I'm now wondering if the .xml files are useful and should be opened along the corresponding .nc file, but I have not found anything about that online. Any idea as to what's going on here?
Thanks

Potentially an issue with the original file. I downloaded it both as the direct link and via .zip and the error persisted. Tried using the raster package and it still did not work. More recent data loaded into R fine. Contact them and raise a ticket.

Same here, as @LTyrone mentioned. Neither R, neither QGIS was able to read the 19790101 nc file properly. No issue with data around 2022.

I’m voting to close this question because the problem is caused by a characteristic of the data files, not a programming issue

I realized that in early years, every second .nc file cannot be read, while the others work fine. I think that's because satellite measurements were taken every second day back in these days. Not sure why the NSIDC added dummy files for missing days. It seems rather confusing.
